# Is soft-O notation transitive?

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science, upper-lower-bounds

We write $f(n) = Õ(g(n))$ if $f(n) = O(g(n)\log^k(g(n))$ for some natural $k$. (we call $Õ$ "soft-O")

My  question is: If $f(n) = Õ(g(n)\log^a(g(n)))$ for some natural $a$, is then $f(n) = Õ(g(n))$ as well?

The question could be rephrased like this: if $h(n) = Õ(g(n))$ and $f(n) = Õ(h(n))$, is then $f(n) = Õ(g(n))$? (which would imply that soft-O notation is in some sense transitive)

I am actually particularly interested in the case when $g(n) = \log^7(n)$ and $a = 1$, but this particular problem also made me interested in the general problem.

I've tried figuring the problem out on my own but I didn't have any idea how to prove this or find a counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is transitive, assuming all functions tend to $\infty$ and you are only interested in the asymptotics as $n\to\infty$. So the functions involved satisfy
$$1\ll\log^m f(n)\ll f(n),\quad\text{for any }m\ge0.\tag{$\star$}$$

Now suppose $h(n)=\tilde O(g(n))$ and $f(n)=\tilde O(h(n))$. This means that $f(n)\le Ah(n)\log^k h(n)$ and $h(n)\le Bg(n)\log^\ell g(n)$ for all $n$ large enough and some constants $A,B,k,\ell>0$. Then (using monotonicity of $\log$): \begin{align*}f(n)&\le A\cdot\left(Bg(n)\log^\ell g(n)\right)\cdot\log ^k\left(Bg(n)\log^\ell g(n)\right)\\&\le C\,g(n)\cdot\left(\log^kg(n)\right)\cdot\left(\log^\ell g(n)\right)\\&
=Cg(n)\log^{k+\ell}g(n),\end{align*}
for some constant $C>0$,
because (by $(\star)$)
$$\log^k\left(Bg(n)\log^\ell g(n)\right)\le3^k\left\{\log^kB+\log^k g(n)+\log^k\left(\log^\ell g(n)\right)\right\}=O\left(\log^kg(n)\right).$$

Comment: How did you get $\log^k\left(Bg(n)\log^\ell g(n)\right)=\log^kB+\log^k g(n)+\log^k\left(\log^\ell g(n)\right)$?

Comment: @HinkoPihPih $\log(ab)=\log a+\log b$ for any $a,b>0$.

Comment: Yes, but you have a power $k$ as well. And $(a + b)^k \neq a^k + b^k$ in general. That's the part that I don't understand.

Comment: @HinkoPihPih Good catch. You can use $(a+b+c)^k\le3^k(a^k+b^k+c^k)$ here and hide the constant $3^k$ in the $O(\cdot)$. I corrected my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm just going to add for potential future readers that this inequality is a special case of [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Counting_measure). The inequality used in the answer is the top inequality from the link for the special case when $n = 3, p = k, y_i = 1$ for all $i$.

Comment: One can also see it as [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) with the convex function $x\mapsto x^k$ on $\mathbb R_+$: $(\frac{a+b+c}3)^k\le\frac{a^k+b^k+c^k}3$. (In fact, this gives the constant $3^{k-1}$.)

Comment: And in case the readers need a more elementary proof which doesn't require any special inequality, you can just multiply $(\log B + \log g(n) + \log(\log^ln))^k$ by brute force (you don't really have to multiply, just see what the summands will approximately look like) and see that the $\log^kg(n)$ summand is going to asimptotically dominate over all other summands..